# findViewById returns null in a listView

Tags: java, xml, null, layout-inflater, findviewbyid

Hi everyone I started coding in java since 2 days and now I'm facing a problem, I found topics that were talking about this, but no one has provided me the right solution.

Im trying to create a "checklist using listView and android BasicAdapter, so I got my row layout xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/procedure_title_text_View"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="@string/procedure_title_default_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/procedure_title_checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/procedure_title_text_View"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I try to add this row layout to my list view **everything works fine** but when I try to change the paramaters of this row layout, like the text in the TextView using this code :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_procedure, parent, false);
        }

        ProcedureTitle currentTitle = getItem(position);
        String titleName = currentTitle.getTitle();
        boolean titleChecked = currentTitle.getChecked();

        //afficher le titre
        TextView currentTitleView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.procedure_title_text_View);
        currentTitleView.setText(titleName);

        //actualiser l'etat de la checkbox
        CheckBox currentTitleChecked = convertView.findViewById(R.id.procedure_title_checkBox);
        currentTitleChecked.setChecked(titleChecked);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The application just crashes and gives me an error like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.protostage2_v1, PID: 21321
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.protostage2_v1.adapter.ProcedureTitleAdapter.getView(ProcedureTitleAdapter.java:69)
```

So I tried to run it with the debug mode, and I found that the line (below), returns a null result. The TextView is then not located and causes the crash of the application.

```
TextView currentTitleView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.procedure_title_text_View);
```

I really dont understand why it does that, the "R.id.procedure_title_text_View" is not null when I look at it in debug mode, I'm looking to try to fix this, if you have any idea on how to solve it, I would appreciate your help ! :)

Comment: This is something I'd like you to try real quick, since it doesn't feel like an answer but, have you tried findViewById() and not convertView.findViewById() ? just removing convertView.

Comment: the fact is that if i don't use the convertView (the layout inflater), i'm not going to use my adapter inside a view and it's going to work, i think. I tried it it only produces more errors hehe

Comment: Please refer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536210/java-lang-nullpointexception-in-custom-adapter-getview> using viewholder might solve your issue

Comment: @Nazifha Even while using the viewholder, this time the "holder.title"  returns a null object reference... I really dont understand